# What type of knife befits peeling/skinning melons and squashes?

Tags: knives

I prefer to peel/skin melons (e.g. watermelon, honeydew) and squashes (butternut squash, pumpkins), rather than [cutting and slicing into wedges](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-cut-up-a-watermelon-step-by-step-tutorial-221100). I depict some catalogues beneath.

1. Which type of knife fits?
2. Serrated or non-serrated?

http://blog.house.com.au/know-knives-buying-knives-taking-care/

[image]

https://shiraleelodge.weebly.com/

[image]

Comment: I want to say "kitchen axe" because that just looks ridiculous, but I just use my chef knife

Comment: @moscafj : use the kitchen axe to trim off the ends (so you're working with a flat bottom), then a more sensible knife to shave the ends off.  I personally start with a cleaver for the ends of the firmer stuff, but I use a narrower bladed knife (eg, boning of carving) as they're easier to curve as you go.

Comment: FWIW, for squashes I don't use a knife at all.  I use a heavy-duty, all-steel serrated peeler.  Doesn't work for watermelons, of course, but works for everything else, and much less chance of taking your fingers off.

Comment: You want to skin it whole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to be dealing with large, slippery things, with tough skins.

It's really easy to cut yourself with these.

For softer ones - melons - a serrated knife works well in my experience.  A regular bread knife will often be too thin, but a heavier knife with serrations works fine.

For harder items - the fall/winter squashes - I use a shorter-bladed chef's knife or utility knife so that I have more control.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with John Feltz' answer it you need to keep the fruits whole, (as you might, say, with a pineapple) But if you're going to section the fruit, I'd use a stiff scallop-serrated bread knife to cut it safely in the first place (having trimmed a flat side, if necessary, to keep the fruit steady while you do that,) and then something more like a filleting knife to work from the inside, aiming to cut the flesh from the peel, rather than the peel from the flesh.